# Google Sheets Script for Headers and Footers

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I have a spreadsheet which I'm using as a form. The user will enter data and then press a button to "submit" it. When the data is submitted, the sheet is copied (except for a few cells). The data is copied by creating a new spreadsheet and copying the values and format since copyTo won't work outside of the same spreadsheet. Is there a way to copy the headers and footers too? Or at least a way to set them using the script?

Comment: This questions is better-suited for StackExchange's WebApps site: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @noogui Besides Range.copyTo methods there is [Sheet.copyTo](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#copytospreadsheet) too

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the [Drive Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app) to (1) [get the file](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#getfilebyidid) using `getFileById("your file's id")`, then (2) [copying](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#makeCopy(Folder)) it using `makeCopy(destination)`

If you wish, after that you can select the second file right away because `makeCopy()` returns the new file. To do that, [get its id](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#getid) with `getId()`, then [select it](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#openbyidid) with the Spreadsheet Service using `openById(id)`. Now that the new file is selected, you can edit it with Apps Script.